# How to reverse a PHP while loop including incremental numbers starting with last number of varying length?

Tags: php, loops, increment, reverse

I have a working php code which made a numerical loop counting up from 1.

```
<?php

$i = 0; // define number

  while (have_rows('the_rows')) : row(); // begin while loop

  $i++; // increase increment with each loop ?>

  <div>
     <?php echo $i; // outputting the number ?>
  </div>

<?php 
    endwhile; // end while loop 
?>
```

This code will loop through all available entries and stop after there are no more entries. It will count up for each `$i` output.

For example, it might look like this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

There is no pre-set number. It could be any number including 1, 5, 74, or 938 entries. The loop will continue to all entries and stops after all entries are finished.

This works fine if I start at one. But since the number is not fixed, looping backwards is a tad more difficult.

How can I reverse this loop so that first of all, it counts the numbers backwards (e.g. if there are 7 rows, it counts backwards from 7), and also to reverse the loop starting with the last row?

e.g.

```
<div>7</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>1</div>
```

Comment: What is `row()`?  There needs to be a way of getting the number of rows or all rows into an array before you know what number to start from.

Comment: Just a note: no mysql access. Needs to be PHP code only.

Comment: For simplicity I didn't post my whole complicated page of code that would convolute the question. `row()` simply is where my row is fetched in the php code. It checks if row exists and if so posts the next row.

Comment: How does the `while` loop terminate after `row()` has finished getting its entries?

Comment: @JonathanLam `endwhile` .

Comment: @asegfvawer That is not how a loop works. A `while` loop runs all the code in its block until the condition is not met. See: [while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Comment: *funny how people who don't know the answer just downvote to feel good about themselves. I'm just ignoring any downvotes.*

Comment: @JonathanLam I'm not here to argue about the definition of a while loop. My code **works perfectly**. I just want to reverse it now.

Comment: @asegfvawer I asked about the loop because I wanted to make sure it wasn't a cause of error. The updated loop makes more sense.

Comment: yes I added the inside of the while so it made more sense to you. by the way it is also encased in an `if` (have rows) / `endif`. fyi. I tried to only include relevant code for simplicity.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: Yes because of the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the length of the data, get the length of the data and then print it out, in reverse.

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  while(has_rows('the_rows')):
    row();
    $i++;
  endwhile;

  while($i > 0):
?>

  <div><?php echo $i--; ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I didn't add all of the code in. There is a lot more code, I shortened the code for simplicity of the question.

Comment: How will your code output the full increments? You echoed $i outside of the loop and also outside of the rows

Comment: @asegfvawer I wasn't aware that there was more code. You might want to add ellipses or mention that in your code

Comment: @asegfvawer What do you mean "output the full increments?" All your code did was print out numbers in increasing order, up to the length of the array; my code does the opposite (printing numbers from the length of the array down to zero. I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: @asegfvawer The second `while` loops is to reverse the order of the first `while`. It iterates through the elements in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the number of rows in advance and without looping twice, you have several options.

One is to build an array and reverse it:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (have_rows('the_rows')) : row();
    $i++;
    $html[] = "
    <div>
     $i
    </div>";
endwhile;
echo implode(array_reverse($html));
```

Or prepend each one onto an array:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (have_rows('the_rows')) : row();
    $i++;
    $html = "
    <div>
     $i
    </div>";
    array_unshift($data, $html);
endwhile;
echo implode($data);
```

Or prepend the new string to the existing one:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$html = "";
while (have_rows('the_rows')) : row();
    $i++;
    $html = "
    <div>
     $i
    </div>$html";
endwhile;
echo $html;
```

However this looks like WordPress or something, so I would think there would be a way to get the number of rows before the loop.

Comment: After looking further I like your code and am going to try it. Looks like it may be a great solution. Will post an update after I tried in a few minutes.

Comment: In example, 1, where is `$data`? I see it output, but where is it defined? Also, you can add in php inside the `$html` without opening and closing php or converting html to php?

Comment: ah, makes much more sense, I thought you might be outputting the `$html` but wasn't sure cause you had wrote `$data`. Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: How do I include both html and php inside the `$html`? I tried it but it doesn't look like I can put both php and html inside the array without closing tags or maybe converting the html to php.

Comment: **Edit** I think the problem is because I have both single and double quotes inside, double for html e.g. `class=""` and single for php e.g. `item('an_item')`. I'll need to fit this diverse code inside the array. How to do that? can I convert array to use a single `$html[] = '` and escape the php inside which uses the same like `item(\'an_item\')`? Or something else?

Comment: No luck on escaping the `\'`. It outputs nothing.

Comment: ok. I am almost there I think. I used this `$html[] = "  <div>$i</div> ";` and that does output the numbers backwards. I had to remove the `;` after `$i;` to get the numbers to output.  But to get the html code I had to escape all the `\"`. So, like this `class=\"theclass\"` Now the html outputs. But the other php code is still outputting as text. For example I need this `item('an_item')` to run as php code, but instead it is outputting to the screen as plaintext into each row, like `item('an_item')` as text instead of the php that is supposed to be running.

Comment: I tried to use the dot to make the php code run, like this ` . item('an_item') . `, but no luck on that front. Instead, it just outputs blank. If I don't use the dot then it outputs the php code as plain text. How to get the php code to run inside the array?